# Reading general file

Tags: c, unix

I'm making a program that reads in a file from stdin, does something to it and sends it to stdout.

As it stands, I have a line in my program:

```
while((c = getchar()) != EOF){
```

where `c` is an int.

However the problem is I want to use this program on ELF executables. And it appears that there must be the byte that represents EOF for ascii files inside the executable, which results in it being truncated (correct me if I'm wrong here - this is just my hypothesis).

What is an effective *general* way to go about doing this? I could dig up documents on the ELF format and then just check for whatever comes at the end. That would be useful, but I think it would be better if I could still apply this program to any kind of file.

Comment: Your hypothesis is wrong. This is the canonical way to read a stream.

Comment: why do you want to use stdin? this means you would be doing prog < file. What is wrong with using prog file then just reading the file yourself? An executable is going to contain all sorts of values, not just ASCII.

Comment: @Sasquiha Eh? Maybe he wants to write a filter. That's the way UNIX commands are supposed to work.

Comment: @Neil, kinda know what you mean, look at sort, etc. can work on both parameters and through a pipe. OP kind of imples that the program is specifically going to read a file on stdin.

Comment: Remember to open the file in `binary` mode so that no translations, such as 0x1a == EOF are performed.

Comment: @Thomas There ain't no file, and maybe he wants text mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll be fine - the `EOF` constant doesn't contain a valid ASCII value (it's typically `-1`).

For example, below is an excerpt from `stdio.h` on my system:

```
/* End of file character.
   Some things throughout the library rely on this being -1.  */
#ifndef EOF
# define EOF (-1)
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to go a bit lower level and use the system functions like open(), close() and read(), this way you can do what you like with the input as it will get stored in your own buffer.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it correctly.

**EOF is not a character.** There is no way `c` will have EOF to represent any byte in the stream. If / when `c` indeed contains EOF, that particular value did not originate from the file itself, but from the underlying library / OS. EOF is a signal that something went wrong.

**Make sure `c` is an `int` though**

Oh ... and you might want to read from a stream under your control. In the absence of code to do otherwise, `stdin` is subject to "text translation" which might not be desirable when reading binary data.

```
FILE *mystream = fopen(filename, "rb");
if (mystream) {
    /* use fgetc() instead of getchar() */
    while((c = fgetc(mystream)) != EOF) {
        /* ... */
    }
    fclose(mystream);
} else {
    /* error */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the getchar(3) man page:

> Character values are returned as an
>   unsigned char converted to  an int.

This means, a character value read via getchar, can never be equal to an signed integer of -1. This little program explains it:

```
int main(void)
{
        int a;
        unsigned char c = EOF;

        a = (int)c;
        //output: 000000ff - 000000ff - ffffffff
        printf("%08x - %08x - %08x\n", a, c, -1);
        return 0;
}
```